# Export ImageCases to Python?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, mxnet-format

I’d like a tutorial on how to export a bounding box detector network to mxnet, (for bonus points: convert to Tensorflow), and then get it running correctly in python!

Some related questions exist for pythonizing simple recurrent and classification nets, but not for the network backing`ImageCases`. Seems there is a lot of MMA glue code to get inference off the ground, which is what makes this a worthy question.

You can access it as follows:

```
NetModel["Wolfram ImageCases Net V1"]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't believe the ImageCases network is published, but, from a question I put during a livestream, it's a variant of YOLO underneath. I would recommend just using a version of YOLO native to Tensorflow.

Comment: @CarlLange it's undocumented, but there

Comment: Thanks for adding it to your question. And indeed, it doesn't seem to be exactly like YOLO.